# Ruby syntax error - unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this error in Rails 4.1.4, but I can't see where should be the problem:
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post= Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

Comment: looks ok... can you please post the stack trace.

Comment: for which action you got that error?

Comment: it may be the problem in your view , you can check view file also

Comment: in browser i have marked last end

Comment: app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Comment: I do not see any error: i can just add this file to my project and it parses correctly.

Comment: @user2883301: Check your model and view also

Comment: it is not in view because when i delete last statement under private, it works. incorrectly, but without syntax error.

Comment: model is empty: class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Comment: could you please delete the whole create def ? just for testing purpose.

Comment: @pictonica: try changing this line `render 'new'` to `render action: 'new'` once

Comment: @anusha same error. it only works when i delete (post_params) in method create and whole def post_params statement under private, so problem should be there i think.

Comment: @pictonica: Try adding like this once: Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :content) and remove private method

Comment: @anusha pure genius. thanks a lot!

Comment: @pictonica: Shall i post this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in `new` method

```
Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :content)
```

and remove that private method

Answer (score 0):

The Problem i see with is with where you declared the private method, you did not indent the `post_params` method properly and the private method has no "end"

Do this instead..

```
private
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
 end
end
```